How to Display Internal UI for MariaDB MSI Prerequisite in WiX Bootstrapper?
I am creating an MSI installer for my software using WiX Toolset in Visual Studio 2022. One of the prerequisites for my software is MariaDB (available as an MSI file).
In my WiX installer, I am adding MariaDB as a prerequisite using the <MsiPackage> element in a bootstrapper project. I set the DisplayInternalUI attribute to yes because I want the user to configure the installation location and set the root password via MariaDB’s UI dialog boxes. However, the MariaDB installer runs silently without displaying any dialogs.
Here’s the code I used for the MariaDB prerequisite:
<MsiPackage
SourceFile="path\to\mariadb.msi"
DisplayInternalUI="yes"
/>

As a side note, when I add Notepad++ as a prerequisite using the <ExePackage> element, the dialog boxes are shown as expected:
<ExePackage
SourceFile="path\to\notepad++.exe"

/>
Both packages are included in the same bootstrapper project, but the behavior for the MariaDB MSI file is different. It installs silently, even though I specified DisplayInternalUI="yes".
Here are my questions:

Does the DisplayInternalUI attribute not work for some MSI packages
like MariaDB?
How can I force the MariaDB installer to display its
UI for configuring installation options (like setting the root
password)?
Are there any additional steps I need to take for MariaDB
to allow user configuration during installation?

Additional Information:

WiX Toolset version 3.14
Visual Studio 2022
MariaDB v11.3.2 MSI file
Using a bootstrapper project

